# PDO database class review

Tags: php, classes, pdo

I've taken this class and made it my own but I'm curious to know what other think of it? Are there things I'm missing? Anything you can recommend?

```
class Database {
    private $host = '';
    private $user = '';
    private $pass = '';
    private $dbname = '';

    private $dbh;
    private $error;
    private $stmt;

    public function __construct() {
        $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=' . $this -> dbname . ';host=' . $this -> host . '';
        // Set options
        $options = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        // Create a new PDO instanace
        try {
            $this -> dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this -> user, $this -> pass, $options);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $this->error = $e -> getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function query($query) {
        $this -> stmt = $this -> dbh -> prepare($query);
    }

    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null) {
        if (is_null($type)) {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int($value) :
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value) :
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value) :
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default :
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this -> stmt -> bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }

    public function execute() {
        return $this -> stmt -> execute();
    }

    public function fetchAll() {
        $this -> execute();
        return $this -> stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function fetch() {
        $this -> execute();
        return $this -> stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function rowCount() {
        return $this -> stmt -> rowCount();
    }

    public function countAll($arr) {
        return count($arr);
    }

    public function lastInsertId() {
        return $this -> dbh -> lastInsertId();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have set up something very similar with a couple changes. In `__contruct()` I assign the credentials to variables, then call an instance to start the `PDO` connection. I also use `try-catch` for each PDO statement to make sure that I am not getting any errors.

```
private $_pdo = null;
private $_host, $_dbname, $_uname, $_pass;
private $_sql, $_result;
private $_preparedStmt;

public function __construct($host, $dbname, $username, $password) {
    // You could run checks here to make sure that...
    // no values or specific values are not equal to ''
    $this->_host = $host;
    $this->_dbname = $dbname;
    $this->_uname = $username;
    $this->_pass = $password;
    $this->startPDO();
}

// ... Later on in code, under Private functions comment tag
private function startPDO() {
    try {
        $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->_host.';dbname='.$this->_dbname, $this->_uname, $this->_pass);
        $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        //$this->handleFatalErr($e->getMessage(), 'connection'); // 'die' error handling
        //$this->handleErr($e->getMessage(), 'connection'); // Non-'die' error handling
    }
}
```

In each function I check the connection, I would recommend something similar. You could either kill the script if there is no connection or you could re-connect using the current variables `$this->_host`, etc:

```
public function query($sql) {
    $this->checkConnection();
    $this->_sql = $sql; // This is used for logging and for a getter function
    try {
        $this->_result = $this->_pdo->query($this->_sql);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        //$this->handleFatalErr($e->getMessage(), 'connection');
    }
}

private function checkConnection() {
    ($this->getPDO() === null) ? die('There is no connection to the database, please re-establish connection.') : NULL;
        //$this->handleFatalErr(self::ERR_CONNECTION_LOST, 'CONNECTION_LOST');
}

private function getPDO() {
    return $this->_pdo;
}

public function close() {
    (isset($this->_pdo) && $this->_pdo != null) ? $this->_pdo = null : NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private $host = '';
    private $user = '';
    private $pass = '';
    private $dbname = '';

    // ....

    public function __construct() {
        $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=' . $this -> dbname . ';host=' . $this -> host . '';

        // ...
    }
```

Two things here:

- How can I set the connection credentials? The properties are private and I see no setters or parameters to the constructor?
- Why use PDO if you only use mysql?

And an other thing:

```
public function bind($param, $value, $type = null) {
    if (is_null($type)) {
        switch (true) {
            case is_int($value) :
                $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                break;
            case is_bool($value) :
                $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                break;
            case is_null($value) :
                $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                break;
            default :
                $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
        }
    }
    $this -> stmt -> bindValue($param, $value, $type);
}
```

This can be dangerous. Let's say you have code like this:

```
$db->bind('param', $_POST['id']);
```

Your method would detect it's a string, but it should be an integer!

After all your class doesn't bring much value, it mostly forwards calls to PDO.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The connection details are entered in the class itself with the private variables. I just took them out. Thanks for the param suggestion. Also, why doesn't this class bring value? It speeds up my process and handles PDO.

Comment: @SeanWM Most of the methods just forward the calls to other methods (And passing some constants, BTW you could set the fetch mode in pdo with the following function too: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php). Except the `bind()` method, which IMO is dangerous to use. It's basicly a wrapper which reduces the functionality (because you can only use it for mysql in your case, and only a certain set of PDO methods) and security.

Comment: `$db->bind('param', $_POST['id']);` in my demo I just ran, it does in fact NOT return this as a string for me.  It works as expected

Comment: @jasondavis I can not reproduce that. Every `$_POST` value I pass is treated as string (because it is a string). Did you cast it before passing it to the function?

Comment: @Mogria I confess I didn't test a REAL post, only simulated so I get what you are saying, perhaps his function could be modified though to detect int